# Why is my MSBuild publishing as a zip file?

Tags: azure-devops, msbuild, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

Why is my Azure DevOps CI build publishing my code as a zip archive?

what am I doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

This generates a WebApi.zip.
I would like to have folders because I want to copy and create folder in my structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use `FileSystem` rather than `PackageLocation` like below:

```
/p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem /p:publishUrl="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\" /p:DeployDefaultTarget=WebPublish
```